# Magento shopping cart 'Get a Quote' & 'Update Total' buttons redirects out of shopping cart

Tags: magento, redirect, button

So my issue is when a customer uses the 'Get a Quote' feature for their shipping and tax, after they choose their country, state, zip - and when the 'Get a Quote' button is pressed, it then redirects them to the home page (index) of the site. The quote does successfully appear in the cart, but you have to click back into the cart to see it after you're redirected. Secondarily, when you go back to the cart, after you choose your shipping method (the radio buttons for shippers) and click 'Update Total' the same thing happens - redirected out of cart. The only thing I've changed in the shipping.phtml file is the headers, I never changed any of the JS code or anything.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This could be caused by a php or js error. Check your php error log.

Comment: I checked all logs and I don't see anything causing this.